# How can I make an UEFI USB tools stick?

Tags: operating-system

In the past I had an BIOS (MBR) USB tool stick with a few ISO tools on it, which could be used as an emergency tool stick.

But how can I make such a USB stick with more ISOs on it for UEFI (GPT)? I do know Rufus, but there I can only make one ISO bootable on the stick. Is there a solution to make a multi-ISO UEFI boot stick with some tools on it?